# WPF: context menu in TreeViewItem binding to root

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I have TreeView control and I need to bind property from root (window/usercontrol) DataContext in context menu in that treeview.

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBox>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="{{ BINDING TO HEADER PROPERTY FROM WINDOW DATACONTEXT}}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
    public string Header { get { return _header; } set { _header = value; } }
```

I've tried multiple things: I've added `x:Name="WindowRoot"` to Window and `{Binding Header, ElementName=WindowRoot}` but it didn't work, I've tried multiple FindAncestor and RelativeSource but it didn't work.

Can someone help me?

#### Edit:

This is simplified case, in my normal application I use `Unity + Prism`, so `ViewModel` is AutoDiscovered (`prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`) and it generally works. By "works" I mean: TreeView shows items from my collection, so it is connected, the problem is with context menu binding only.

In this **simplified** example I have ugly and simple code-behind, because I only want to test this ContextMenu binding:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
    private string _header = "testtest";
    public string Header { get { return _header ; } set { _header  = value; } }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Items.Add("ItemTest");
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding DataContext to your binding so DataContext.Header

Comment: @NicolasPierre Thanks for the idea, sadly it doesn't work too (it works finein TextBox which is directly in Window, so it is not problem with the property Header)

Comment: Is your DataContext properly bound ?

Comment: Should I do anything beside `window.DataContext = MyViewModel`? Binding in the `<TextBox Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBox>` above `TreeView` works fine.

Comment: Edit your question with how you bound  the viewmodel if you would please

Comment: @NicolasPierre Edited

Comment: Going on a limb here (not behind a computer). Try implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your Window class and using it on the header property

Comment: Sadly it is not the case (and I have implemented it correctly - I have tested it in TextBox)

Comment: Then I don't know at this time. I'll check back later if you still need help

Comment: That would be great, thanks in advance, here's the code, if you wanted to test https://gist.github.com/BAndysc/96b61af38fb4fbc951d57a82d280d453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `TreeViewItem` to the parent window or user control using a `{RelativeSource}` and then bind the `Header` property of the `MenuItem` to the `Tag` property of the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

The reason you cannot bind directly to any property of the window from the `MenuItem` is that a `ContextMenu` resides in a different element tree than the parent window or user control.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works flawlessly! Thanks again.